# Wpdatatables conditional rule in row

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins, conditional-statements

I am using the wpdatatables plugin to list a group of apartments.
I had an idea to use a plugin for listing apartments, which would have columns: square footage, number of rooms, floor, status, link to the apartment plan, link to the page with the form. My question was about a situation in which if the status of the apartment changes to "sold", it will affect another specific cell with a link in a different column in the same row.

Is there no way to hide the contents of a cell in a row with some javascript code? I will be very grateful for tips on solving the problem. Kind regards

I tried

```` ```

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table_1");
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
if (cells.length > 1 && cells[0].innerText === "SOLD") {
  cells[1].style.display = "none"; 
}

}
});

</code>

but not working ````

Comment: `cells[0].innerText === "SOLD"` - if there is any whitespace before or after the text in the cell, then this won't match. Trimming the innerText first, before you compare, is always a good idea in such situations. If that doesn't help - then we need more info from you - an example, of what the HTML actually looks like. Please go read [ask] and [mre], if you have not done so yet.